# DB2 SQL for Join: Duplicate Table Designator B Error

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have a ColdFusion query like this:

```
    SELECT a.Description, b.MCDL01 
    FROM ( SELECT GMDL01 as Description from F0901_LB where GMMCU = '950ALDA77') a, F0006_LA b
    Inner Join b on a.GMMCU = b.MCMCU
```

Basically, the value of `GMMCU` in `F0901_LB` table exists as `MCMCU` in `F0006_LA` table. And I need to grab all matching `MCDL01` from the `F0006_LA` table. But my join above gives error:  `Duplicate table designator B not valid.`

BTW, I am not fully sure an `Inner Join` is needed but trying it to see what happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean ` SELECT a.Description
, b.MCDL01
  FROM ( SELECT GMDL01 as Description
         ,GMMCU
         from F0901_LB
         where GMMCU = '950ALDA77'
       ) a
Inner Join F006_LA b on a.GMMCU = b.MCMCU;`

Comment: @mao - That is exactly the same (except for the mistakes you made) as my answer I posted 5 mins before your comment.  Why are you posting a comment that is the same as my answer but harder to read because it is a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different syntax for joins here you want this (preferred):

```
SELECT a.Description, b.MCDL01 
FROM ( SELECT GMDL01 as Description, GMMCU 
       from F0901_LB 
       where GMMCU = '950ALDA77') a
Inner Join F0006_LA b on a.GMMCU = b.MCMCU
```

this is the old way of doing it which you might have seen, but is not the best way to do it:

```
SELECT a.Description, b.MCDL01 
FROM ( SELECT GMDL01 as Description, GMMCU  
       from F0901_LB 
       where GMMCU = '950ALDA77') a, F0006_LA b 
where a.GMMCU = b.MCMCU
```

Comment: THX! The first one gives error: Column GMMCU not in table A in *N.

Comment: the second one also gave: Column GMMCU not in table A in *N.

Comment: @Meengla -- please make sure you are using the most current version -- I made two changes.

Comment: Yes sir. My query is much simplified above and so I will need to plug in your sql in a few minuts.... Thanks

Comment: The simplified query worked. But when I put in a whole lot of fields--the I am getting  Column GMMCU not in table A in *N.

Comment: @Meengla -- that was the change I made, I added the column GMMCU to the list of fields you select.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it?

```
SELECT a.MCDL01, b.GMDL01 Description 
FROM F0006_LA a inner join F0901_LB b on a.MCMCU = b.GMMCU and b.GMMCU = '950ALDA77'
```